# Working on a express app with React frontend, git add -A doesn't add client changes?

Tags: reactjs, git

Hi I'm building my first express app with a React client running concurrently. When I git add -A in the server folder it adds everything but the changes made in the client(React) folder stay red and un-added. I pushed anyway, cd'ed into the client folder, git add -A and made a git commit -m message, but when I went to git push it says there is No configured push destination. When I cd back into the server folder and git push, it says everything up to date. When I git status I still see un-pushed changes in the client folder in red. On the github website's repository, the client folder is unclickable. Any help?

```js
-.git
-client
--.git
--src
--package.json
--node_modules
-package.json
-node_modules
```

edit: Here is what part of the git status looks like:

```js
modified:   client (modified content, untracked content)
```

Comment: am confused: are the client and server folders holding separate git repositories?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Ah yes upon second review it looks like both the client and server both have a .git folder. I must have `git init`ed in the client folder on accident. However the client git is not linked to any repository. I currently have some changes added to be committed in the client's git, will it be safe to `rm -rf .git` in the client folder?

Comment: you need to create a new git repo in the parents of both folders, then  you can simply delete the `.git` directories in the client and server folders. WARNING: once you delete there's no going back! (what is bump? i'm not familiar with this)

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Thanks! So I `git init` in the parent of the server, which was parent of the client. Then I `rm -rf .git` in both the client and then the server folder. Then I `git init` in the server and was able to push all changes to a brand new repository. then I `rm -rf .git` in the parent of the server. Seemed to work out, thanks! I'm not sure if making a new git repo in the parent folder was necessary though, or was that a fail safe?

Finally - 'bump' is a forum term that usually refers to commenting on a topic and thus 'bumping' it to the top of a forum, increasing visiblity to users

Comment: I'm assuming that you wanted a single repository for both the server and client folders? also i don't think you can bump with Stack overflow

Comment: Yes, that's right! And because the client is a child in the server folder I was able to use one repo in the server folder. And thanks, good to know that about Stack overflow. But what would be the best way to bring attention to a question that hasn't been answered? I tried to repost a different question earlier and it was flagged and deleted.

Comment: FYI, git has complex rules with regards to nested respositories. to answer your last question you can offer a "Bounty". but mainly the question has to be clear, and interesting enough for people to answer